# debug/AndroidManifest.xml выделяет многие атрибуты красным

Tags: android, gradle, manifest

Причём, я сделал всё, что следует делать в таких случаях:

1. Invalidate Caches/Restart
2. Sync project with gradle files
3. Просто переоткрывал манифест
4. Изменял манифест через блокнот (Удалил пробел и сохранил), а потом перезапускал
5. Пробовал Fetch External resource, но он выдаёт ошибку:
   Error while fetching http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
6. Закрывал проект через Close project и запускал его через Import Project (Gradle, Eclipse, ADT)

Но ничего мне не помогло. Ошибка возникла внезапно, ничего до этого с манифестом я не делал
На любом атрибуте пишет Attribute (имя атрибута) is not allowed here
Есть идеи, как решить эту проблему?

[image: Ошибки в манифесте]

Comment: Просто закройте файл манифеста и снова откройте его. Я думаю поможет.

Comment: Я закрывал и открывал манифест несколько раз, не помогло

Comment: А если так: скопировать содержимое вашего проекта куда-нибудь, удалить существующий проект и создать новый и вставить содержимое.

Comment: Думал об этом, к счастью, проект на гитхабе есть, проще откатить. Просто у меня теперь ещё одна проблема, решения которой у меня нет. И если она повторится, придётся опять отказывать, спасибо